# what is difference between JSON generator and JSON parser?

Tags: apex, force.com, webservices, json, apexrest

I am in learning phase and strucked that what to choose JSON generator or JSON parser when response is coming from 3rd party and type REST webservice.

In Apex guide it showing

Using the JSONGenerator class methods, you can generate standard JSON-encoded content.
Use the JSONParser class methods to parse JSON-encoded content.

Can anyone please guide me with example.

Answer (score 8):

The two are opposite features. The JSONGenerator takes data input and outputs JSON strings. The JSONParser takes JSON string input and outputs objects.

If you're sending data to an outside source, either for a client calling your code, or sending data to a server, use the generator. If you're receiving data from an outside source, either from a client or from a server response, use the parser.

```
/*************************************************************************\
|  /--------\  Call to SFDC    /-----------\   Http Callout   /--------\  |
|  |        | ---- Parser ---> |           | -- Generator --> |        |  |
|  | Client |                  | Apex Code |                  | Server |  |
|  |        | <-- Generator -- |           | <--- Parser ---- |        |  |
|  \--------/   Return Data    \-----------/   Http Response  \--------/  |
\*************************************************************************/
```

However, if you want efficient code, you should use neither, and stick with JSON.serialize, JSON.deserialize, or JSON.deserializeUntyped. JSON.serialize is a quicker version of the JSONParser, and the deserialize methods are a quicker version of the JSONGenerator.

The JSONGenerator has an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm), which I'll copy-paste for you here:

```
public class JSONGeneratorSample{

    public class A { 
        String str;

        public A(String s) { str = s; }
    }

    static void generateJSONContent() {
        // Create a JSONGenerator object.
        // Pass true to the constructor for pretty print formatting.
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        // Create a list of integers to write to the JSON string.
        List<integer> intlist = new List<integer>();
        intlist.add(1);
        intlist.add(2);
        intlist.add(3);

        // Create an object to write to the JSON string.
        A x = new A('X');

        // Write data to the JSON string.
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField('abc', 1.21);
        gen.writeStringField('def', 'xyz');
        gen.writeFieldName('ghi');
        gen.writeStartObject();

        gen.writeObjectField('aaa', intlist);

        gen.writeEndObject();

        gen.writeFieldName('Object A');

        gen.writeObject(x);

        gen.writeEndObject();

        // Get the JSON string.
        String pretty = gen.getAsString();

        System.assertEquals('{\n' +
        '  "abc" : 1.21,\n' +
        '  "def" : "xyz",\n' +
        '  "ghi" : {\n' +
        '    "aaa" : [ 1, 2, 3 ]\n' +
        '  },\n' +
        '  "Object A" : {\n' +
        '    "str" : "X"\n' +
        '  }\n' +
        '}', pretty);
    }
}
```

The JSONParser also has an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm), which I've also included here.

```
public static void parseJSONString() {
    String jsonStr = 
        '{"invoiceList":[' +
        '{"totalPrice":5.5,"statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z","lineItems":[' +
            '{"UnitPrice":1.0,"Quantity":5.0,"ProductName":"Pencil"},' +
            '{"UnitPrice":0.5,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Eraser"}],' +
                '"invoiceNumber":1},' +
        '{"totalPrice":11.5,"statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z","lineItems":[' +
            '{"UnitPrice":6.0,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Notebook"},' +
            '{"UnitPrice":2.5,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Ruler"},' +
            '{"UnitPrice":1.5,"Quantity":2.0,"ProductName":"Pen"}],"invoiceNumber":2}' +
        ']}';

    // Parse entire JSON response.
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        // Start at the array of invoices.
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                // Advance to the start object marker to
                //  find next invoice statement object.
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    // Read entire invoice object, including its array of line items.
                    Invoice inv = (Invoice)parser.readValueAs(Invoice.class);
                    system.debug('Invoice number: ' + inv.invoiceNumber);
                    system.debug('Size of list items: ' + inv.lineItems.size());
                    // For debugging purposes, serialize again to verify what was parsed.
                    String s = JSON.serialize(inv);
                    system.debug('Serialized invoice: ' + s);

                    // Skip the child start array and start object markers.
                    parser.skipChildren();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 

// Inner classes used for serialization by readValuesAs(). 

public class Invoice {
    public Double totalPrice;
    public DateTime statementDate;
    public Long invoiceNumber;
    List<LineItem> lineItems;

    public Invoice(Double price, DateTime dt, Long invNumber, List<LineItem> liList) {
        totalPrice = price;
        statementDate = dt;
        invoiceNumber = invNumber;
        lineItems = liList.clone();
    }
}  

public class LineItem {
    public Double unitPrice;
    public Double quantity;
    public String productName;
}
```

As you can see, reading and writing are both very tedious to do, and you should consider using these classes only as a last resort.

Comment: In addition to readability (worse using these classes) I am curious how the performance compares. With serialization/deserialization being so slow on the platform, I imagine these must be faster, but even so it doesn't seem worth the tradeoff.

Comment: @AdrianLarson JSON methods are approximately 10-15% faster than JSONGenerator/JSONParser methods, and you don't have to write your own custom parsing loops. I suspect that, internally, the JSON methods use the parser/generator classes, but are still more efficient because the runtime does not check for governor limits as frequently inside built-in methods. Of course, that's only conjecture, but seems to make sense logically.

Comment: So more hassle and slower. I feel even better about my disdain for their use.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hey, they're just as useful as String.equalsIgnoreCase...

Comment: At least that doesn't add a bunch of LOC and hurt readability though. I'd take one line of useless over some of the 200+ LOC parsers/generators I've seen that *could* have been one line.

Comment: I only just came across these... I really can't decide what I think of that generator class, could it really be worth using?

Comment: @MattLacey It's a convenience feature for converting Java to Apex Code, as far as I can tell. I don't think I've ever seen an example of JSONGenerator that performs better (in terms of LOC or CPU) than simply using JSON.serialize. If you can find a counterexample, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Ok that'd make sense. Just couldn't think of a reason for it's existence... was building up JSON as a string yesterday for an external API which is why I came across this.